# docker-compose create services with a loop

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to create services in a loop with docker-compose rather than typing all the services by hand? (See example below of creating 100 workers with appropriate ports)

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
  worker1:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5001:5001"
  worker2:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5002:5002"
  worker3:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5003:5003"

  ...

  worker100:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "5100:5100"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can probably do it with the `--scale` option, so if you run `docker-compose up --scale worker=100` it should do exactly what you want.

The [documentation for docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) references this as follows:

> ```
> --scale SERVICE=NUM        Scale SERVICE to NUM instances. Overrides the
>                            `scale` setting in the Compose file if present.
> ```

Comment: How to map ports in case of using scale option?

Comment: I found the solution.
            ports:
            - "ports_range:container_port"

Answer (score 0):

it's very weird that no one not mentioned it. You can easily use the `replicas` future just like the below example to create as many replications as you want instead of the for loop it's very useful. Check doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#replicas)

```
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
    image: dockersamples/examplevotingapp_worker
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 6
```

You also need to use `docker-compose --compatibility up` to make Docker accept a deploy section without using swarm